# RxJava2 Single does not handle error even if doOnerror is provided

Tags: rx-java2, vert.x

I've encountered an issue using RxJava2 (version 2.2.2). See the code below:

```
client.get("/iic-router/health").rxSend()
    .doOnError(err -> { err.printStackTrace(); async.complete(); })
    .doOnSuccess(v -> async.complete())
    .subscribe();
```

As you can see, the rxSend() method returns an instance of `Single`. When I run this code and the WebServer is not started I get an error of Connectiong Refused (as expected), but I get an error:

```
io.reactivex.exceptions.OnErrorNotImplementedException: The exception     
was not handled due to missing onError handler in the subscribe() method call.
```

If I change the code for more traditional way on RxJava like this:

```
client.get("/iic-router/health").rxSend().subscribe(
     v -> async.complete(), 
     err -> { err.printStackTrace(); async.complete(); }
);
```

Everything works well. Anyone can help me ? Or it's a real bug ?

Comment: `doOnError` allows you to side-effect an error if it happens and is **not an error handler** as the error will continue downstream regardless.

Answer (score 5):

This is not a bug and the simple `subscribe()` is [documented](http://reactivex.io/RxJava/javadoc/io/reactivex/Single.html#subscribe--):

> Subscribes to a Single but ignore its emission or notification.
>
> If the Single emits an error, it is wrapped into an `OnErrorNotImplementedException` and routed to the RxJavaPlugins.onError handler.

The [OnErrorNotImplementedException](http://reactivex.io/RxJava/javadoc/io/reactivex/exceptions/OnErrorNotImplementedException.html) said that you need to implement the onError Handler, like you did in your second example.

Instead of `doOnError`, you can also try [onErrorResumeNext](http://reactivex.io/RxJava/javadoc/io/reactivex/Single.html#onErrorResumeNext-io.reactivex.functions.Function-) or [onErrorReturn](http://reactivex.io/RxJava/javadoc/io/reactivex/Single.html#onErrorReturn-io.reactivex.functions.Function-) which won't invoke `onError` on subscribe.